# Values of enum as result of a function

Tags: c#

I have three enums:

```
enum ValueType : int
{
  FloatingPoint = 2,
  .../...
}
enum ConstraintType : int
{
  Range = 2,
  .../...
} 
enum Parameter : int 
{
  ExposureTime = F(ValueType.FloatingPoint, ConstraintType.Range, 23),
  .../...
}
```

The problem is in the signature of `F` if I use:

```
private static int F(ValueType _V, ConstraintType _C, int _N) { ... }
```

I get an error (invalid arguments) for every call in the definition of `Parameter`, but if I use the following instead:

```
private static int F(int _V, int _C, int _N) { ... }
```

Everything is fine.

It's not a blocking problem, but I'd like to understand why is that.

Comment: how are you calling F? Are you passing ints or enums as params?

Comment: @kristian: That's stated in the question :-) See the first code block. (I didn't see it at first, either.)

Comment: @O.R.Mapper how did that sneak in there?! ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The C# spec states in section 14.3 ("Enum members") that

> Within an enum member initializer, values of other enum members are
>   always treated as having the type of their underlying type, so that
>   casts are not necessary when referring to other enum members.

As far as I can tell this is why the arguments appear to have a type of `int`. It's interesting to note that this will not result in an invalid argument error:

```
ExposureTime = F((ValueType)ValueType.FloatingPoint, 
                 (CostraintType)ConstraintType.Range,
                 23),
```

Of course it will still result in *another* error because you cannot use a method call to initialize enum members as Marc says. A method call is not a constant expression, while

> The associated value of an enum member is assigned either implicitly
>   or explicitly. If the declaration of the enum member has a
>   constant-expression initializer, the value of that **constant
>   expression**, implicitly converted to the underlying type of the enum,
>   is the associated value of the enum member. If the declaration of the enum member has no initializer, its associated value is set implicitly [...]

Answer (score 7):

For enums with explicit values, the value must be a constant expression. `F(...)` is **not** a constant expression. Regardless of whether the parameters are `int` or enums, you cannot assign an enum value from a function call.

Your "everything is fine" actually means:

> The expression being assigned to 'blah.Parameter.ExposureTime' must be constant

The only "problem" here is that the compiler doesn't give a very elegant error message to a particular illegal scenario.

Comment: Actually the compiler does give the expected error message if the method signature is modified to accept ints.